# How to find which element to use with Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to log in to this website but it's created with js, I think it is React which I have no experience.

This is an image of inspected code of the website that I try to log in.

[image]

I tried this...

```
email_field = browser.find_element_by_name('input_login_3kzbI')
email_field = browser.find_element_by_id('login-modal-email')
```

and then it should go this, but it fails on the line above...

`email_field.send_keys("pepero.guy@gmail.com")`

Comment: The first one is wrong (that's its class, not its name).  The second one is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_element_by_name`  checks against `name` attribute, and `find_element_by_id`  checks against `id` attribute. There is no such attributes for the `input` element, so it failed.

Try this: `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@qa-id="login-modal-email"]')`